# Surface area given a function in polar without converting to rectangular

Tags: calculus, 3d, polar-coordinates, surface-integrals

Note: I need to use the double integral method of integration for this.

Let's say I have a function in terms of $r$ and $θ$: $f(r, θ)$

For a rectangular function $f(x, y)$, one can use the following formula to find the surface area:

$$\int\int_D\left(\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}\right)dA$$

Is there a formula for doing it with a function of $r$ and $\theta$?

**Update:**

Let's say we have the function $f(r, θ)=9-r^2$ and have the restriction $2≤r≤\sqrt{6}$.

So, it would go from [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mcnuu3gjihu9fdf/ellipticParabaloid.gif) to [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4xv3chn2dt1sduo/ellipticParabaloid2.gif).

So, to answer the question of what I am looking for, let's say I want the surface area of the function, I would want the surface area of the above function with the above restriction. It could probably somehow be done using [the same reasoning](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIPolarCoords.aspx) that one uses the substitution rule, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Yes and it's given by the substitution rule for multiple integrals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_(area)

Comment: @CyclotomicField  I don't think the substitution rule works since the above mentions fx and fy. If you can provide such a formula using the substitution rule, please answer below. I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: This is arguably the most common application of the substitution rule in all of mathematics so I'm confident it works. The explicit formula is in the link provided which I assume you didn't bother to read. As I have made the effort to provide an explanation I would ask you make some effort to understand it before I provide additional assistance.

More so I really don't understand why you feel the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ would exclude the substitution rule. I would encourage you not to reject results based on intuition as it will continue to lead you astray.

Comment: Are you referring to [this?](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/91b80d79c6bc8a4a265145bedfd8cdbc864eba37) I understand that a function of x and y once plugged in can substitute f(x, y) with f(r, theta) using the substitution, but I was referring to if I originally had a function of r and theta and didn't want to convert to rectangular before making it into a double integral for surface area in given bounds. I apologize if it seemed that I didn't read the link you gave, but I did so and still do not understand how you would do so without converting to rectangular first.

Comment: Well the problem then becomes what do you mean by area? It's typical to approximate the area under a curve using rectangles which are strongly linked to rectangular coordinates. You'd have to decouple what you mean by area from approximating rectangles before you can do that meaningfully. This can be done using the notion of measure which abstracts what we mean by area so that you can do calculations in this way, but it requires certain properties to be satisfied by the construction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Comment: I added an update. I hope it helps! @CyclotomicField

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your surface $S$ is given in the form $z=f(r,\theta)$, where $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates in the $(x,y)$-plane, then this is equivalent to a parametric representation
$$(r,\theta)\mapsto {\bf r}(r,\theta)=\bigl(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta, f(r,\theta)\bigr)$$
with a domain $D$ to be specified by inequalities referring to $r$ and $\theta$. For the area element on $S$ we have to compute
$${\bf r}_r=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta, f_r\bigr),\qquad {\bf r}_\theta=\bigl(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,f_\theta\bigr)$$
and then 
$${\bf r}_r\times{\bf r}_\theta=\bigl(f_\theta\sin\theta -rf_r\cos\theta ,-r f_r\sin\theta-f_\theta\cos\theta,r\bigr)\ ,$$
so that
$$|{\bf r}_r\times{\bf r}_\theta|=\sqrt{r^2(1+ f_r^2)+f^2_\theta}\ .$$It follows that the area of $S$ is given by
$${\rm area}(S)=\int_D\sqrt{r^2(1+ f_r^2)+f^2_\theta}\>{\rm d}(r,\theta)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

If the function is already in polar coordinates you don't need to do the substitution, it's already in the right form. You will still need to integrate $f(r,\theta)r$ instead of $f(r,\theta)$ to calculate the correct area as though you had done the substitution. This is because we typically define area with regards to rectangular coordinates and need to convert back to calculate all of the approximating rectangles when setting up the integral even though the function was never in the form $f(x,y)$.